# Can't update SASS to 3.4

Tags: terminal, rubygems, sass

I'm trying to make the most of the latest SASS 3.4 features but can't seem to update the gem.

When I type in terminal on OSX 10.9.4:

```
sass -v
```

I get the following response:

```
Sass 3.2.10 (Media Mark)
```

When I type:

```
gem update sass
```

I get:

```
Nothing to update
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I remember having a similar problem awhile ago. What does `sass -v` say when you open a new Terminal window? Because in my case, the terminal window I ran the update in, kept showing me the old version number, even after a succesful update.

Answer (score 12):

Try install and cleanup:

```
// will install last version
gem install sass
// will delete old versions
gem cleanup sass
```

After this reinstall the latest version of compass

```
// will install last version
gem install compass
// will delete old versions
gem cleanup compass
```

Comment: I managed to get to the latest version of SASS but that didn't solve my issue.

I didn't realise that Compass uses it's own version of Sass!

I updated Compass to the --pre version which supports SASS v 3.3.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Compass 1.0 now works with Sass > 3.3, reinstall compass first so you get the latest version